# How to pass optionparser arguments through pylint?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pylint

**test.py**

```
 from optparse import OptionParser
    
    
    class Test(object):
        def __init__(self):
            pass
    
        def _test1(self, some_val):
            print(some_val)
    
        def main(self, some_val):
            self._test1(some_val)
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        parser = OptionParser()
        parser.add_option("-a", "--abcd", dest="abcd", default=None,help="some_val")
    
        (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
        val = options.abcd
    
        mainobj = Test()
        mainobj.main(val)
```

Above script works, when executed `python test.py --abcd=wxyz`
When I run `python -m pylint test.py --abcd=wxyz` , doesn't execute.

**Error:**

```
strong text    Usage: __main__.py [options]
    
__main__.py: error: no such option: --abcd
```

How to execute through pylint ?
Can you please help me ?

Comment: I don't see why you would want to do that. I don't think there is a point in doing such a thing. _pylint_ doesn't care about those arguments. Calling `python -m pylint test.py` is probably what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send new arguments like that using Pylint

Pylint is a static code analysis tool. It does **NOT** run your program. Therefore it does not matter what arguments are sent to the main program you want to test. Imagine it tests your code as it was "text" without running it.
Also the syntax you are using in the command line is not right, because after`-m pylint` the arguments which are sent are actually **Pylint's arguments**. Pylint has it's own set of options and rules you can set. you can view a summary [here](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/features.html)
or just type in your command line this:

```
pylint --help
```

The error message you get is a Pylint error. if you want to change the options you insert to Pylint you would have to change its source code i reckon...

Hope I understood your question correctly and that it helps.